# Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 arguments, 1 given

Tags: php, mysqli

I am doing a simple copy and paste for class into a connect.php file to connect to my sample database "fun" The code is below and when I try to connect I get

> Connection established.
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 arguments, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\connect.php:10 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\connect.php(10): mysqli_select_db('fun') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\connect.php on line 10

```
<?php
 $db_host = "localhost";
 $db_username = "root";
 $db_passwd = "";
 $db= @mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_passwd) or die ("Could not
connect!\n");
 echo "<h1> <font color=green>Connection established.<br>"; 
 $db_name= "fun";

@mysqli_select_db ("$db_name") or die ("Could not select the database $dbname!\n");
 echo "<h2> <font color=blue>Database $db_name is selected.<br>";
 echo "<br><font color=red>\"Today was good. ;
?>
```

Is there supposed to be something else in () besides $db_name? I'm not sure what other argument it needs.

Comment: Get rid of the `@`s, read the manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php

Comment: What isn't clear about that error message?

Answer (score -3):

You can do it in the following way:

```
$mysqli->select_db($db_name);
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT DATABASE()")) {
  // success
} else {
  // error
}
```